# Groups with only one element of order 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am doing some exercises in [Algebra: Chapter 0](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~jarekw/pdf/Algebra0TextboookAluffi.pdf). In the second chapter, we are asked to prove the following:

> $G$ is a finite group with a unique element $f$ of order $2$. Then $\operatorname{\Pi_{g\in G}}g=f$.

This result is highly plausible. If we multiply the elements in the order of \begin{equation}e\cdot f\cdot \text{elements of order 3}\cdot\text{elements of order 4}\cdots,\end{equation} and pair elements with their inverses, then we get $f$, since it is the only element that does not have a couple.

However this is only one possible order of multiplication, and we know that in general different order give different results.

So I wonder how we can do the general case. Thanks!

Comment: Clearly, the group $G$ is from even order.

Comment: It's not true for arbitrary orders of the group elements. For example, in the quaternion group $Q_8$ the product can be either $f$ or the identity.

Comment: You need to change it to **finite abelian group**. See http://www.math.fsu.edu/~aluffi/algebraerrata/Errata.html (p.49)

Comment: @DerekHolt: In fact for any $g\in G$ there is a $n$ such that $g^n\in H=\langle f\rangle$. So the product of all elemnts would be $f$ or $e_G$. Right?

Comment: (The author even says: "My personal favorite is the missing abelian at p.49, Exercise 1.8.")

Comment: @Amr, yup its not possible if its not Abelian, marked my answer for deletion.

Comment: @BabakSorouh, that's the most I could prove passing to the quotient $\,G/\langle x\rangle\,$ , with $\,x\,$ the only involution. What's also true is that the product of all the elements in an *odd* order group is always contained in the group's derived subgroup.

Comment: It is not true that you have only one element without a pair - the identity element does not have a separate inverse either. Not important in this case as it doesn't affect the answer, but one to be aware of when counting elements (e.g. the argument that a p-group has non-trivial centre by examining the size of conjugacy classes).

Comment: @BabakSorouh, let $\,G=\{g_0:=1,g_1,...,g_n\}\,\,,\,n\,$ an even natural, be a group. In the quotient group $\,G/G'\,$ we have that the factors of the product $$\prod_{i=0}^n(g_iG')$$ are commutative, so we can pair each coset $\,g_iG'\,$ with  $\,g_i^{-1}G\,$ and we thus get...

Comment: @BabakSorouh, knock yourself out. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general we have a result about the order of elements that says $|aba^{-1}|=|b|$ for all $a,b\in G$.

Let $p=\left|\prod_{g\in G} g\right|$

Using this result, **assuming $G$ is abelian**, we can steadily "remove" pairs $(a,a^{-1})$ from $p$. However, $f$ is the only element which is its own inverse, so this process stops when we have $p=|f|=2$. But $f$ is the only element of order $2$ in $G$, so

$$\prod_{g\in G} g = f$$

Comment: You seem to be assuming $\,G\,$ is abelian, which is *not* given.

Comment: You have a word of elements of $G$ and cannot use that property without assuming $G$ is abelian, so I agree with Don.

Comment: Of course, you are right. I apologize.

Comment: The question is, do we have $|abcb^{-1}d| = |acd|$ in a non-abelian group? Because if we do, then your result holds; you can remove pairs $(b, b^{-1})$ from the word without changing the total order. I don't know, but by conjugation by $d$ above, we can rename $da$ to $a$ and explore whether $|abcb^{-1}| = |ac|$

Comment: It's clear that in any nonabelian group you can get at least two different products of all group elements, by using different orders.

Comment: Thanks! But for abelian groups it is trivial, and actually my problem already contains the idea of the proof.